# Get window username and domain name using angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I need to get window username(Enviorment.UserName) and domain name(Environment.DomianName) using angular. Is it possible using angularjs.

Comment: If `Environment` is a global object you have full access to it anywhere in your angular app controllers, directives,  services etc and all you need to do to display it in DOM is declare a scope variable for it.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is a client side application and only has access to the variables that are delcared in the browser's `window` object. The Environment object is something that is only accessible on the server by default. Depending on what type of application you are creating, you can use Razor or ASP language to do something like:

```
// c#
public static string UserDomainName { get; }

// cshtml / aspx (JavaScript)
<script>
  // add to global window object (not recommended, but will work)
  window.yourUserNameVariable = @UserDomainName; // or <%=UserDomainName %> if asp
</script>
```

Comment: so what is the alternate solution for this problem?

Comment: I need system username and domain name, not the angular.js Environment variable.

Comment: Angular does not have an Environment variable. It is simply a client-side library, like jQuery. It only has access to what the browser has access to, like the DOM, and other JavaScripts. What type of application are you making? Can you provide some code?

Comment: Since it is a client side only application. does it make sense to use it in a Domain Centric Environment?  All of our security is driven by Domain Groups.

Comment: It doesn't matter what front end framework you use and it doesn't matter that it's domain centric. Any front end library is fine (Angular / React / Solid etc)