# Get windows client username in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am developing a little application in nodeJS and AngularJS. all my clients are windows machines, and they are all in the same domain.

I want to add some text label in the page like " Welcome ! USERNAME" .

how can get the Windows username of the client when he gets homepage?
I read about passport and node-sspi, but didnt understand how to implement that.

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow user 'azium', explains in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831198/get-window-username-and-domain-name-using-angular-js) response that

> "AngularJS is a client side application and only has access to the
>   variables that are delcared (sic) in the browser's window object. The
>   Environment object is something that is only accessible on the server
>   by default."

However, according to [Arhsim Tima](http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/1be0c50/get-windows-user-name-using-javascript.html) you can try the following javascript,

For IE:

```
var objUserInfo = new ActiveXObject("WScript.network");
document.write(objUserInfo.ComputerName+"<br>"); 
document.write(objUserInfo.UserDomain+"<br>"); 
document.write(objUserInfo.UserName+"<br>");  
var uname =  objUserInfo.UserName;
alert(uname);
```

For Firefox:

```
function getUser() {
   return Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment).get('USERNAME');
}
```